# calculate sum of (current due,past due,past due 30,past due 60 and over 90) from column and compare with last column Ar_exposure

Tags: java, arrays, collections, flatfilereader

calculate sum of values (current due,past due,past due 30,past due 60 and over 90) from column and compare with last column Ar_exposure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlZaA.jpg)

so far I tried code below:

```
public class Employee {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\user123\\Desktop\\test.txt"));
                
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
        
        int linenumber =1;
                    
        String[] ColumnName =null;
        
        ArrayList<String[]> value = new ArrayList<String []>();
        String line;
        
        String[] arr;           
        
        while(reader.ready())
            
            if(!(line=reader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
                
                arr =line.split(";");
                
                if(linenumber==1)
                    ColumnName = arr;
                else
                    value.add(arr);
                linenumber++;
                
            }
                

        for (int i=0;i<ColumnName.length;i++) {
            ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
            
            for(int j=0;j<value.size();j++) {
                
                ar.add(value.get(j)[i]);
                map.put(ColumnName[i], ar);
                            
            }
            
            System.out.println(map);
        
        }
    }   
}
```

Im able to capture the values from column but Im unable to add values.

Comment: `.add` on a `Collection` does not _sum_ the values.  It adds another value to the `Collection`.

Comment: @BeUndead Hi , any other approach/solution to the above problem?